# How to access particular key value from rest webservice xml response in moodle

Tags: web-services, xml-parsing, moodle

```
<RESPONSE>
<SINGLE>
<KEY name="id"><VALUE>2</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="username"><VALUE>admin</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="password"><VALUE>$2y$10$7M7tcqJDwqmKZRenKGyB8.SYLMkErOSRgrLDd/bxDCBMJyVpTMKlO</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="firstname"><VALUE>Admin</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="lastname"><VALUE>User</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="email"><VALUE>nihar.cbsh@gmail.com</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="skype"><VALUE></VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="phone"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="city"><VALUE></VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="country"><VALUE></VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="lang"><VALUE>en</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="avatar"><VALUE null="null"/>
</KEY>
<KEY name="timemodified"><VALUE>1401336631</VALUE>
</KEY>
```

I got this xml response from rest webservice in moodle. I want to fetch the username value from a particular key. How can I get it?

Comment: What programming languages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jaxb to convert XML in to java object (and vice versa) and fetch the values from that object. [This tutrial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) and [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) will guide you.